# Lifetime issues with rocket fairings, tokio-scheduler and crons

Tags: rust, cron, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

I'm currently building an API engine on top of Rocket, and as modern apps do, I wanted to include an automated scheduler to run async tasks (aka crons) while the Rocket API is running.

I decided to use Rocket fairings to enable the said scheduler built around tokio-schedule on the "liftoff" event.

The fact is, I set up all the required parts (logging into database, structs and traits), but I get a strange error while compiling regarding lifetimes of my fairing.

Here is a walk through of my code :

-> this is my "command" module, containing all structural parts to build and move commands (aka crons) with my application.

```rust
/// Synthetize a command execution result.
pub enum CommandResult {
    SUCCESS,
    ERROR(String),
    SKIPPED(String),
}

/// Trait to define structs as runnable async crons with tokio_scheduler
#[async_trait]
pub trait Command: Send + Sync {
    /// returns the current command name
    fn get_command_name(&self) -> String;

    /// returns the current command argument payload
    fn get_command_args(&self) -> Option<HashMap<String, String>>;

    /// returns the "cron_middleware"
    fn get_cron_middleware(&self) -> CronLogMiddleware<CronLogRepository>;

    /// real body for the command execution, must be overriden in impls.
    async fn do_run(&self) -> Result<CommandResult>;

    /// starts the command process by validating command lock, and registering an open cron log into database.
    async fn begin(&self) -> Result<CronLog> {
        // ...
    }

    /// ends the command process by releasing command lock, and registering the result of the command to an opened cron log into database.
    async fn end(&self, cron_log: &CronLog, result: CommandResult) -> Result<()> {
        // ...
    }

    /// hidden runner of commands, uses begin, end and do_run, and will be used by runner.
    async fn run(&self) -> Result<()> {
        // ...
    }

    /// generates a unique key for this command name + args, for locks purposes
    fn generate_unicity_key(&self) -> String {
        // ...
    }

    /// converts command args as a string payload
    #[allow(clippy::or_fun_call)]
    fn get_command_args_as_string(&self) -> String {
        // ...
    }
}

/// struct to move a command + its cron schedule into scheduler.
pub struct CommandHandle<T: Command + ?Sized + Send + Sync> {
    pub command: Box<T>,
    pub schedule: String,
}
```

Then, for testing purposes, I created a test command struct like this :

```rust
/// a testing purpose command
pub struct TestCommand {
    pub name: String,
    pub args: Option<HashMap<String, String>>,
    pub cron_log_middleware: CronLogMiddleware<CronLogRepository>,
}

#[async_trait]
impl Command for TestCommand {
    // accessors (get_... functions)

    async fn do_run(&self) -> Result<CommandResult> {
        debug!("executed !");

        Ok(CommandResult::SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

The rocket builder looks like this :

```rust
    let mut sched = CronScheduler::default();

    sched.add_cron(CommandHandle {
        command: Box::new(TestCommand {
            name: "app:test".to_string(),
            args: None,
            cron_log_middleware: cron_log_middleware.clone(),
        }),
        schedule: "*/1 * * * *".to_string(),
    });

    // then I add sched to rocket with .manage()
```

And the fairing looks like this :

```rust
/// a rocket fairing enabling async tasks (eg crons) while rocket is launching
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct CronScheduler {
    crons: Vec<CommandHandle<dyn Command>>,
}

impl CronScheduler {
    /// adds a cron (eg CommandHandle with a given command) to run with the scheduler.
    pub fn add_cron(&mut self, cron: CommandHandle<dyn Command>) {
        self.crons.push(cron);
    }
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CronScheduler {
    //...
                        v -- error is here
    async fn on_liftoff(&self, _rocket: &Rocket<Orbit>) {
        let sched = SchedulerBuilder::build().await;

        for handle in self.crons.iter() {
            let job = Job::new_cron_job_async(handle.schedule.as_str(), |_uid, _lock| {
                Box::pin(async move {
                    handle.command.run().await;
                })
            })
            .unwrap();

            sched.add(job).await.unwrap();
        }

        sched.start().await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Aaaand I get this error :

```
error[E0759]: `self` has lifetime `'life0` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/core/fairings/cron_scheduler.rs:34:26
   |
34 |       async fn on_liftoff(&self, rocket: &Rocket<Orbit>) {
   |                            ^^^^ this data with lifetime `'life0`...
...
39 | /                 Box::pin(async move {
40 | |                     handle.command.run().await;
41 | |                 })
   | |__________________- ...is used and required to live as long as `'static` here
   |
note: `'static` lifetime requirement introduced by the return type
  --> src/core/fairings/cron_scheduler.rs:34:5
   |
34 |       async fn on_liftoff(&self, rocket: &Rocket<Orbit>) {
   |       ^^^^^ requirement introduced by this return type
...
39 | /                 Box::pin(async move {
40 | |                     handle.command.run().await;
41 | |                 })
   | |__________________- because of this returned expression
```

And my cargo toml shortened:

```ini
[dependencies]
rocket = {version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"]}
// ...
tokio-cron-scheduler = {version = "0.8.1", features = ["signal"]}
// ...
```

I tried different solutions, and remarked that this is the Command that is causing issues, as if I replace the content of the "Box::pin(...)" with something like a println!, nothing goes wrong.

I don't know if it's a conflict between async-trait and rocket async traits, or else, but I cannot figure it out.

Edit 1: shortened alot of code 'cause the ticket was way too long.

Edit 2: solution found thanks to the validated answer ; here is the final code patched if it can help anyone.

FTR, I did have to impl Clone myself (not using macros) and used the code of the pinned answer as a reference.

```rust
// command 

pub struct CommandHandle<T: Command + ?Sized + Send + Sync> {
    pub command: Arc<T>,
    pub schedule: String,
}

impl<T> Clone for CommandHandle<T>
where
    T: Command + ?Sized + Send + Sync,
{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            command: self.command.clone(),
            schedule: self.schedule.clone(),
        }
    }
}

// fairing 

    async fn on_liftoff(&self, _rocket: &Rocket<Orbit>) {
        let sched = SchedulerBuilder::build().await;

        for handle in self.crons.iter() {
            let schedule = handle.schedule.clone();

            let handle = handle.clone();

            let job = Job::new_cron_job_async(schedule.as_str(), move |_uid, _lock| {
                let handle = handle.clone();

                Box::pin(async move {
                    handle.command.run().await.unwrap();
                })
            })
            .unwrap();

            sched.add(job).await.unwrap();
        }

        sched.start().await.unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you reduce it to a [mre]? That would help future viewers, and makes it easier to answer. Also on the way you might find a solution yourself.

Comment: [`Job::new_cron_job_async`](https://docs.rs/tokio-cron-scheduler/0.9.1/tokio_cron_scheduler/struct.Job.html#method.new_cron_job_async) requires that your closure is `'static`, but it is not since `handle` is a reference to `self.crons`. Either clone it, take it, or arc it.

Comment: Ok, shortened the issue as @cafce25 requested.

Comment: @kmdreko can you explain this please ? I cannot clone command as it's a trait and I cannot apply Clone trait to a trait, and I don't know how to use Arcs in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Job::new_cron_job_async`](https://docs.rs/tokio-cron-scheduler/0.9.1/tokio_cron_scheduler/struct.Job.html#method.new_cron_job_async) requires that your closure is `'static`, but it is not since `handle` is a reference to `self.crons`.

Taking a quick look at your structure, if you use `Arc` instead of `Box` in `CommandHandle`, then it is easily cloned and thus can give a `'static` handle to the cron job:

```
pub struct CommandHandle<T: Command + ?Sized + Send + Sync> {
    pub command: Arc<T>, // <------------
    pub schedule: String,
}

impl Clone for CommandHandle ...
```

```
for handle in self.crons.iter() {
    let handle = handle.clone(); // <------------               vvvv
    let job = Job::new_cron_job_async(handle.schedule.as_str(), move |_uid, _lock| {
        let handle = handle.clone(); // <------------
        Box::pin(async move {
            handle.command.run().await;
        })
    })
    .unwrap();

    sched.add(job).await.unwrap();
}
```

Its hard to verify since your posted code is incomplete, but I believe you need both clones above since the function needs ownership to be `'static`, but also must be `FnMut` in order to be called multiple times, so the handle can't be moved into the `async` block directly.

Comment: Dude I owe you one more ! (I remember you already saved me from a diesel issue)

I noticed in your code that you impl `Clone` not with macro, so I did it and used your code and it works !

Correct code is in the original post.